# switching between tabs in a browser

Tags: automated-testing, selenium

I am trying to click on a download link which will open in a new tab in pdf format.I want to do some actions on newly open tab.

I am able to switch to newly open tab but when I am trying to do any operation its giving exception "no such element exception" bcoz of still it is focused on previous tab

```
driver.get("http://somewebsite.com/");
driver.findElement(By.id("download")).click();  //By clicking on this it will open a new tab 
for(String winHandle:driver.getWindowHandles()){
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
}
```

Comment: In question, Please put code which you tried

Comment: It should work , still you can use wait command before click on element of that newly open tab.

Comment: Its resolved by adding sleep statement after click statement.Thanks @Helping Hands

Comment: @QAMember I would look into `WebDriverWait` and `ExpectedConditions` rather than using Thread.sleep.  (If that's what you meant)

Comment: @QAMember - That's great to hear...

Comment: Hello @Julian Cleary,can you give me the code for webdriverwait ? .Bcoz I am not sure what to use in ExpectedConditions wait until opening a new window

Comment: Since you resolved it by using the sleep method, you can use the WebDriverWait method , and then use the ExpectedConditions to test if the required element is present or test if the visibility of element located is true.

Comment: Here the problem is  new tab will open a PDF file so I can not use wait until element is visible..@log_file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is the working code for switching  between two tabs

```
driver.get("http://somewebsite.com/");
driver.findElement(By.id("download")).click();  
thread.sleep(3000);
for(String winHandle:driver.getWindowHandles()){
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle); 
}
```

Comment: using a static sleep is bad practice

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend something like this.  Sometimes on window change there is no guarantee you have window focus such as when browser is configured to NOT change to new tab when new tabs open:

```
driver.get("http://somewebsite.com/");
driver.findElement(By.id("download")).click();  
Sleeper.sleepTight(3000); // new window should have focus at this point
getLatestWindowFocused(driver);
```

There are a million ways you can do this, but here is an example, and it all depends on what happens to work for you:

```
public static void getLatestWindowFocused(WebDriver driver) 
{
    String mostRecentWindowHandle;
    for(String winHandle:driver.getWindowHandles()){
        mostRecentWindowHandle = winHandle;        
    }
    driver.switchTo().window(mostRecentWindowHandle);
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    js.executeScript("window.focus();");
    js = null;
}
```

Comment: Hello @djangofan, Thanks for your enhanced answer .Can you please provide some explanation about below line
"myUtilityClass.forceWindowFocusWithJavascriptExecutor(driver);"

Comment: Ok, I updated it.  The answer is meant for you to read between the lines.

Answer (score -2):

```
ArrayList<String> tabs2 = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(1));
```

Comment: Code without explanation (and formatting) is usually not good. Please consider to add some information.